# NullValueHandling must be an optional parameter for the JsonFormatter attribute

Tags: properties, null, breeze

Hope developers team wouldn't miss my message. NullValueHandling must be an optional parameter for the JsonFormatter attribute because there are a lot of cases when properties of the object required on client side independently of their value. 
And I personally got some troubles trying to identify why my object doesn't have half of it properties.

By the way limitation for DbConext and entity namespace to make the entity observerable on client side is not good too.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the question here. Could you rephrase it so we know what you are asking? If this is just feedback for the Breeze team, then you should send it to them on their site instead.

Comment: You are free to substitute your own configuration of the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` for the one Breeze provides when you decorate your Breeze controller with the `[JsonFormatter`] attribute. Examine the code for `Breeze.WebApi.JsonFormatter` to see the settings Breeze expects. Change the settings at your own risk and be sure to test.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about "limitation for DbContext and entity namespace...". Perhaps you can clarify in another question.

Comment: **The "Model/DbContext same namespace" rule has been lifted as of Breeze v.0.83.2** Your entity model and EF DbContext/EFContext classes may reside in different projects with different namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Breeze currently sets NullValueHandling to 'Ignore', so as to minimize payloads by not sending any 'null' values. We did not think that this would be an issue because the json serialized objects are materialized into 'breeze' entities on the client and breeze has metadata to determine what the valid properties for each entity are.

What is the use case for actually sending 'nulls' to the client?  This is an relatively easy enhancement to make if we have a good use case. The only one that comes to mind is with anonymous objects queried from the server for which metadata will not exist.  Is this what you are encountering?

Comment: Yep, exactly. I'm selecting anonymous objects in some cases, and pass them to client. I agree with you approach to minimize the payload, but this should be configurable by developer, because there could be some issues like mine.